# How do i get third digit from right of any given number in cpp?

Tags: c++

How can i get third digit of any given number like this

```
           Input                                       Output
           1234567                                      5
           98765                                        7
```

I have tried this function

```
char nthdigit(int x, int n)
{
    while (n--) {
        x /= 10;
    }
    return (x % 10) + '0';
}
```

But it did not work properly for me

Comment: Define "did not work properly for me" please :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Worked wrongly for me

Comment: @Khaleesi Descriptive. What is this `---`?

Comment: Divide by 100 to get rid of the units and tens digits. Then take remainder mod 10 to get the digit you want.

Comment: @JimVargo Yeah it worked.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following what you want to achieve, your `n--` should actually be `--n`

```
char nthdigit(int x, int n)
{
    while (--n) {
        x /= 10;
    }
    return (x % 10) + '0';
}
```

Then you get what your want: `nthdigit(1234567, 3)` returns 5; `nthdigit(98765, 3)` returns 7;
Although it's not the optimized way.